# Python regex match across multiple lines

Tags: regex, python-3.x, multiline

I am trying to match a regex pattern across multiple lines. The pattern begins and ends with a substring, both of which must be at the beginning of a line. I can match across lines, but I can't seem to specify that the end pattern must also be at the beginning of a line.

Example string:

```
Example=N      ; Comment Line One error=

; Comment Line Two.

Desired=
```

I am trying to match from `Example=` up to `Desired=`. This will work if `error=` is not in the string. However, when it is present I match `Example=N      ; Comment Line One error=`

```
config_value = 'Example'
pattern = '^{}=(.*?)([A-Za-z]=)'.format(config_value)
match = re.search(pattern, string, re.M | re.DOTALL)
```

I also tried:

```
config_value = 'Example'
pattern = '^{}=(.*?)(^[A-Za-z]=)'.format(config_value)
match = re.search(pattern, string, re.M | re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use

```
config_value = 'Example'
pattern=r'(?sm)^{}=(.*?)(?=[\r\n]+\w+=|\Z)'.format(config_value)
match = re.search(pattern, s)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YjSu6J).

**Pattern details**

- `(?sm)` - `re.DOTALL` and `re.M` are on
- `^` - start of a line
- `Example=` - a substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=[\r\n]+\w+=|\Z)` - a positive lookahead that requires the presence of 1+ CR or LF symbols followed with 1 or more word chars followed with a `=` sign, or end of the string (`\Z`).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8TG2ML/2).

Comment: I should probably add this to the question. The second string might not be the word Desired. The second string could be any group of characters A-Za-z followed by =.

Comment: @10SecTom Then use `(?=[\r\n]+\w+=|\Z)` lookahead.

Comment: Cheers for the help.

Comment: One last question, I ran the code and the groups return from N to just before the Desire=. If i wanted Example= to be within the match also?

Comment: @10SecTom Just get `match.group(0)`, the whole match. And remove the capturing group if you do not need it, i.e. `(.*?)` => `.*?`.