# Creating a regex pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text file which contains multiple SQL queries that start and end with `"""` or `'''`. I am trying to create a regex pattern to capture all such occurrences and extract all the SQL query content between the triple quotes. Below is what I have tried so far using [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ky66QN/1). The problem is, it is finding only the very first occurrence. How can I modify my code to find all matching occurrences?

Below is my code. I am using Python 3.6.

```
# Example content from the text file
data = """
'''test''',
..................
..................
example text here('''SELECT * FROM table''').format(),
..................
..................
"""

# Creating regex pattern
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=([\"']{3}\b))(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?(?=\1)")

# Searching for patterns
pattern = regex.search(data)

# Printing all patterns
if pattern:
    print(pattern.group()) # prints only 'test'
```

The expected output is as provided below:

```
[test, SELECT * FROM table]
```

***UPDATE:***
I modified my regex pattern to `((?:'''|\"\"\")\b)(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?(?=\1)` and it works for the above two cases. However, I also have multiline patterns for which the code doesn't work. Below are couple of samples for reference. I looked at some of the already asked questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137113/python-regex-match-across-multiple-lines) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text). But I am unable to figure out how to reconstruct my pattern to capture both single line and multi-line patterns. Any help on this would be appreciated as I am completely new to regex.

```
"""
SELECT * from table
WHERE

A = B

"""

"""SELECT VALUES
FROM table
WHERE score = 0"""
```

Comment: try `re.findall(pattern, string)`

Comment: Try the `re.findall()` function, rather than `.search()`.

Comment: Look into `re.finditer()`

Comment: I have already tried this - `regex = re.findall(r"(?<=([\"']{3}\b))(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?(?=\1)", data)`. But I get an output like this - `[("'''", ''), ("'''", '')]`. The only thing which worked was ~.search()~

Comment: Ditch the `[\"']{3}`, it matches things you don't want (combinations of three *different* quotes). Just use `(?:'''|\"\"\")`.

Comment: Use `re.finditer`. `[x.group() for x in re.finditer(your_regex, text)]`

Comment: Do you know anything more about the structure of the file you're searching through? For example, is it a syntactically valid Python file? If so, you might have an easier time extracting string literals by using the [`tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) module.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, re.finditer() worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @hobbs, I tried it. It gives me this error: `invalid group reference 2'. Here is my regex: `"(?:'''|\"\"\"\b)(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?(?=\1)"`. I am not very confident with creating regex patterns.

Comment: @Code_Sipra no, `((?:'''|\"\"\")\b)` etc.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you're looking for [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20findall#re.findall)